# error PYRO0227 when trying to create WiX patch

Tags: wix, patch

I'm trying to create a patch using WiX 3.6 following [this example](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm) containing 2 C# projects (executable and library). But I'm getting this error:

```
warning PYRO1079 : The cabinet 'RMT.cab' does not contain any files.  If this patch contains no files, this warning can likely be safely ignored.  Otherwise, try passing -p to torch.exe when first building the transforms, or add a ComponentRef to your PatchFamily authoring to pull changed files into the cabinet.
error PYRO0227 : The transform being built did not contain any differences so it could not be created.
```

Executed commands:

```
set w="c:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.6\bin\"

%w%torch.exe -p -xi 1.0.0.0\PatchMe.Installer.wixpdb 1.1.1.1\PatchMe.Installer.wixpdb -out Patch\Diff.wixmst
%w%candle.exe Patch.wxs
%w%light.exe Patch.wixobj -out Patch\Patch.WixMsp
%w%pyro.exe Patch\Patch.WixMsp -out Patch\Patch.msp -t RTM Patch\Diff.wixmst
```

Directories "1.0.0.0" and "1.1.1.1" contain output of two different versions of same projects (changed AssemblyVersion and some code changes).
Patch.wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?include Variables.wxi ?>
  <Patch AllowRemoval="yes"
         Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)"
         DisplayName="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion)"
         Description="Small Update Patch"
         Classification="Update"
         TargetProductName="$(var.ProductName)"
         >
       
        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RMT.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM">
            </PatchBaseline>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="SamplePatchFamily"/>
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>   
        <PatchFamily Id="SamplePatchFamily" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Supersede="yes">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp981D9885AA29DD578D66D32ED919EBFB"/>
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpD5E6EA59DB565F052E0217CB3248DAE5"/>
        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

ComponentRef Id's refers to component fragments create by heat.exe harvest of projects mentioned earlier.

**Any idea, what could be a problem and why transform doesn't contain any changes?**

Comment: This may apply to your situation:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/WIX-users-Patch-in-Wix-3-6-is-empty-warning-PYRO1079-The-cabinet-cab-does-not-contain-any-files-td7335788.html
and
http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/3244/

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a bug in 3.6.  I tried for several hours to get this to work with version 3.6.3303.1, but I always got the PYRO1079 error.  I finally downgraded to version 3.5.2519.0, and the error has not reoccurred.

I had to give up my MediaTemplate node and the Directory attribute of my ComponentGroup node after downgrading.  I don't know if this was part of the solution or not (i.e. this might have fixed the problem instead of the downgrade).